# Filtering rows in a data frame based on value in the last column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove any rows in a data frame if a cell in the last column is empty(Nan). More columns will be added to the data overtime so I just want it to look at the last column.

Here is the dataframe
0   1   2   3   4
aa  bb  cc  dd  1
ae  we  df  gh  Nan
wr  th  fg  rg  Nan

And the expected result
0   1   2   3   4
aa  bb  cc  dd  1

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with test if no missing value in last column by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df[df.iloc[:, -1].notna()]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) by last column:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=df.columns[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks, the Boolean indexing option seems to have worked for me. I also realized that some of the data in the cells of my last column I also don't need. I would like to remove all rows which have a last column with useless values. See examples below. Basically anything that is not a number is a useless value for me.

30  40  50  23  60                       30  40  50  23  60

40  60  45  34  59  ---------->    40  60  45  34  59

RT  FG  BH  RT  DG                     70  34  50  45  34

70  34  50  45  34           

ER  ER  FT  GH  FH

Comment: @barakagwiratabitha - So need `df1 = df[pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, -1], errors='coerce').notna()]` ?